# RxSwift - How to handle different error scenarios with Observable.zip

Tags: ios, swift, zip, observable

I have this code:

```
    ...
    let minMaxReq = networkProvider.getMinMaxAmortization(id: id)
    let emitExtractReq = networkProvider.getEmitExtract(id: id)

    self.isLoading.accept(true)

    Observable.zip(minMaxReq.asObservable(), emitExtractReq.asObservable()) { (minMaxResp, emitExtractResp) in
            return (minMaxResp, emitExtractResp)
        }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] responses in

            let minMaxResp = responses.0
            let emitExtractResp = responses.1

            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.isLoading.accept(false)
            self.getMinMaxAmortizationResponse.accept(minMaxResp)
            self.receiptsCNH.accept(emitExtractResp)

        }, onError: { [weak self] error in

            self?.isLoading.accept(false)
            self?.receivedError.accept(error)

        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In this case all errors from both requests will end up in the onError closure, how can I handle the error from minMaxReq in a different onError closure?

My goal is to make the 2 requests at the same time but handle their error with different closures. How can I achieve this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the *materialize* operator? Maybe it can be useful for the implementation you need. Annex an example of how it is usually used:

```
let valid = network.getToken(apikey)
            .flatMap{ token in self.verifyToken(token).materialize()}
            .share()

valid
    .compactMap { $0.element }
    .subscribe(onNext: { data in print("token is valid:", data) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

valid
    .compactMap { $0.error?.localizedDescription }
    .subscribe(onNext: { data in print("token is not valid:", data) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In that way, you could divide the stream into two and give it the appropriate treatment.

Another option might be to manipulate the error event in the minMaxReq operation. Something similar to:

```
let minMaxReq = networkProvider.getMinMaxAmortization(id: id)
                        .catchError({ error in Observable.empty()
                        .do(onCompleted: { /* Do anything with no side effect*/  }) })

let emitExtractReq = networkProvider.getEmitExtract(id: id)

Observable.zip(...)
```

Here is an article that explains more detail [Handling Errors in RxSwift](https://www.yaircarreno.com/2020/07/handling-errors-in-rxjs-rxswift-or.html)

Comment: this sounds promising. but I'm not sure how I would apply this to my case. I need the code inside the onNext closure to run only when both requests finishes, so i can flip the isLoading animation off.

Comment: how can I make sure both requests are in sync? I know how to do this using group and such but it gets a bit complicated. I think there must be a RxSwift way to deal with this situation that I'm missing

Comment: I understand I have updated the answer with another possible option, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution helpful for me [RxSwift zip operator when one observable can fail](https://www.amarendrasingh.com/rxswift/rxswift-zip-operator-when-one-observable-can-fail/)

Need to catch error before add to zip

```
let request1 = usecase.request1().asObservable()
let request2 = usecase.request2().catchErrorJustReturn([]).asObservable() // fetching some not so important data which are just good to have.Return empty array on error
Observable.zip(request1,request2)..observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
   .subscribe(
      onNext: { //success code },
      onError: { _ in //error code}).disposeBy(bag:myDisposeBag)
```

But I changed a bit the final:

```
let request2 = usecase.request2().catchError { _ in
            return .just([])
        }
```